# Error of Publish infopath forms in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I create one infopath form, I see this error:

> A query to retrieve form data cannot be completed because this action would violate cross-domain restrictions.
>
> If this form template is published to a SharePoint document library, cross-domain access for user form templates must be enabled
>   under InfoPath Forms Services in SharePoint Central Administration,
>   and the data connection settings must be stored in a UDC file in a
>   data connection library in the same site collection.
>
> If this is an administrator-approved form template, the security level of the form must be set to full trust, or the data connection
>   settings must be stored in a UDC file by using the Manage data
>   connection files option under InfoPath Forms Services in SharePoint
>   Central Administration.
>
> An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. Log ID:6932
>
> ```
> Correlation ID:e692623b-fd86-4ba1-89a7-305fbda02762
> ```

I am using user account having administrator privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Below are few suggestions to solve the same:

1)Ensure that the `"Allow cross domain connection"` setting in Central Admin is ticked.

2)If you are behind a proxy server, you will need to add this to your web.config of your SP web application:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy>
  <proxy proxyaddress="http://myproxy" bypassonlocal="true" />
  <bypasslist>
    <add address="mycustomwebservice.com" />
     </bypasslist>
</defaultProxy>
```

3)

1. In the destination farm, download the respective udcx file from http://destination/udl library.
2. Add an authentication element  as per ‘http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772017%28v=office.14%29.aspx’

   ```
   <udc:UseExplicit CredentialType="NTLM">

       <udc:UserId>domain\username</udc:UserId>

       <udc:Password>Password</udc:Password>

       </udc:UseExplicit>

       <udc:SSO AppId="" CredentialType=""/>

   </udc:Authentication>
   ```

Also need to make sure that you have enabled '`Allow user form templates to use authentication information contained in data connection files`' in Central Admin.